# How do parallel trials in GCP Vertex AI work?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

When you make a hyperparameter tuning job, you can specify the number of trials to run in parallel. After that, you also select the type and count of the workers. What I don't understand is when I make two or more trials run in parallel, yet only one worker, each task is said to occupy 100% of the CPU. However, if one task occupies all of the CPU's resources, how can 2 of them run in parallel? Does GCP provision more than 1 machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parallel trials** allows you to run the trials concurrently depending on your input on the maximum number of trials.

You are correct with your statement "*one worker, each task is said to occupy 100% of the CPU*" and for GCP to run other tasks in parallel,

> the hyperparameter tuning service provisions multiple training processing clusters (or multiple individual machines in the case of a single-process trainer). The work pool spec that you set for your job is used for each individual training cluster.

Please see [Parallel Trials Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/using-hyperparameter-tuning#parallel-trials) for more details.

And for more details about Hyperparameter Tuning, you may refer to [Hyperparameter Tuning Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/using-hyperparameter-tuning).